# R: diff() between columns in data table

Tags: r, data.table, difference

I apologize for improper titling.

The `dt` and `d.dt` are respectively the input and desired output.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(10)
dt = data.frame(x=sample(10, 3), y=sample(10,3))
dt = as.data.table(dt)
# > dt 
#    x y
# 1 :6 7
# 2 :3 1
# 3 :4 2

d.dt = dt[, z:=c(-4, 3, NA)]
# > d.dt 
#    x y  z
# 1 :6 7 -4
# 2 :3 1  3
# 3 :4 2 NA
```

The expected`d.dt[, z]` is computed by subtracting the next row of column`x`  by the current row of column`y`.

Comment: Sorry for missing the essential information, just added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the expected output, it seems like we are subtracting the next row of 'x' with the current row of 'y'.  To get the succeeding or next row,  we can use `shift` from `data.table` and use the argument `type='lead'`.

```
dt[, z:= shift(x, type='lead')-y]
dt
#   x y  z
#1: 6 7 -4
#2: 3 1  3
#3: 4 2 NA
```